# How to change ownership of a room?

Tags: discussion, chat

I've got the following room , [SQL room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11391/sql).

Look like the owners haven't been there for some times.

Some peeps I met there would like to put some improvements in it. We were thinking we would need to own the room.

Any suggestions on how to get the ownership of that room or maybe if it is not needed (the idea is to implement a bot like [Charcoal](https://github.com/Charcoal-SE/SmokeDetector) )?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[One](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/785745/kendall-frey) of the room owners:

```
Kendall Frey
chat user since 2012-01-07
last message    5h ago
last seen       16s ago
```

I'd hardly call that "Inactive".

That said, ***if*** you are in a room where room owners *are* actually inactive, you could find a mod on chat, and ask him to claim ownership. I'm not sure how likely you are to get it, but there's no harm in asking.

Comment: I left him a message through the chat channel. Thanks